# How to run Flow training on 2 GPU(s)?

Tags: ray, flow-project

Repost from Wouter J.

How can I run the flow training on GPU(s)?

I'm currently trying to get the `ppo_runner` benchmark to work with my 2 GPU's. However, I can't find any way to make use of these resources. 
What would I need to change in the code to make use of the GPU's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Repost from the Flow team*

Perhaps a good place to start is to learn how to use multiple GPUs through Ray:

https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-ray-with-gpus.html

Learning how to use multiple GPUs with ray will enable you to train with multiple GPUs too because we use Ray RLlib for training.
Although a fair warning: unless your problem is well suited for GPUs (large image input, large neural nets), often than not, training on a multi-thread CPU (e.g. 64-thread Xeon) is much faster than training on multiple GPUs.